# PhpStorm PHPDoc array of object doesn't hint on external file

Tags: php, phpstorm

In my Callback class I have the following definition:

```
/**
 * @var Entry[] of entries
 */
public $entry;
```

When I'm trying to call `$entry[0]` from inside the class php file - PhpStorm knows how to hint me for the type of object.

When I'm trying to do the same thing from a different file which use this class, the IDE doesn't know how to hint for `$entry[0]`;

```
private function processEvent($body)
{
    $callback = new Callback(json_decode($body, true));
    if (!is_array($callback->entry))
        return;
    //iterate through all entries
    foreach ($callback->entry as $entry) {
        $entry->messaging; // - no hints here...
    }
}
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: This should work, I use this everywhere. Try hsing the full qualified namespace

Comment: More complete example is required. You must be missing something as it seems to work OK here. In any case: 1) try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE; 2) Check what IDE thinks about `$callback` and `->entry` property -- invoke `View | Quick Documentation` on them 3) you can always provide local typehint (inside or just above that `foreach` -- `/** @var Entry $entry */`

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the problem. Renaming the class Callback (to Class1) fixed it. Also PhpStorm thinks $callback is of type "callable". So "Callback" is possibly a reserved word. After renaming my class it did not offer any other Callback-implementation.